# Convert JSON array into jQuery array format

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I have some problem converting jQuery JSON object into jQuery array.

I have JSON object like this:

```
[{"1":"2013-10-12","2":3},{"1":"2013-11-16","2":1},{"1":"2013-12-23","2":3},{"1":"2014-02-11","2":8}]
```

and I want to convert this JSON to array but only select the '1' value (2013-10-12) only

use this syntax:

**full syntax**

```
var array_data = [];
var json_data = (function() {
    var json;
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/masterpiece/chartGetTransaction',
        async: false,
        global: false,
        success: function(data) {
            json = data;
        }, 
        error:function(){
            alert("Error loading chart");
        }
    });
    return json;
})();

$.each(json_data,function(index,value){
    array_data.push(value['1']);
});
```

but showing results like this:

`2013-10-122013-11-162013-12-232014-02-11`

I need the format the result to be like this:

`[2013-10-12, 2013-11-16, 2013-12-23, ...]`

Any suggestions?

Comment: There's no such thing as a jQuery array ?

Comment: what do you mean @adeneo?

Comment: `var array_data = arr.map(function(val,ind){return val[1];});`

Comment: Works just fine for me -> http://jsfiddle.net/HvLec/

Comment: You forgot to set the dataType to JSON, you have a string

Comment: @adeneo, i need to convert the array format to be like this: [1,2,3] not using the bracket. thanks.

Comment: @adeneo yes, i see the array works now. thanks for helping.

Comment: No problem, setting the dataType makes jQuery automagically parse the returned data, otherwise you'll always have a string.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `forEach`

```
array = []
[
    {"1":"2013-10-12","2":3},
    {"1":"2013-11-16","2":1},
    {"1":"2013-12-23","2":3},
    {"1":"2014-02-11","2":8}
].forEach(function(element) { 
    array.push(element[1]);
});
```

Comment: And that's different from using jQuery's $.each how exactly ?

Comment: @adeneo I don't know exactly, but it's built-in the language, so there may be some performance enhancement, though I've not benchmarked it so I don't know. If pure javascript is enough for what you have to do, I've always learned that then you don't need jquery :)